# off-canvas navigation menu isn't functioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, canvas, navigation

I don't what is going on, but if anyone can help me that could be great. So I'm trying to create a navigation menu that is off-canvas for mobile layouts, but I've been running into issues; and I'm at a dead end right now. If someone can take a look at my code and point me in the right direction that would be great.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/javascript/mobilnavprotoscript.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/javascript/modernizr.custom.64630.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/mobilnavstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
    <title>Welcome to My Domain</title>
</head>
<body>
        <nav id="toggle" class="main">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Other Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>       
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="mobilmenu"><a href="#toggle" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>       
        <header>
            <h1>This is a placeholder <br />
                for header</h1>
        </header>
               <div id="content">
                <article class="content-main">
                    <section>
                        <h2>Heading goes here...</h2>
                        <time datetime="2014-05-21T02:43:00">Officialy Posted On May 21<sup>st</sup> 2:35 A.M.</time>
                        <p>Content will go here...</p>
                    </section>
                </article>
                <aside>
                    <p>More content soon...</p>
                </aside>
                </div>
        <footer>
                <div class="copyright">
                    <span>All rights reserved 2014.</span>
                </div>
            <nav class="foot">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Other Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </footer>
        </div>               
    </body>
 </html>
```

Here's the css that's neccesary for what I'm trying to do (Please do let me know if there's any other parts of my css you need to see.):

```
nav#toggle
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 15.750em;
left: -15.750em;
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transition: 0.15s ease;
height: 100%;
}

nav#toggle.active 
{
transform: translate(15.750em, 0px);
}

nav.main
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: 'bebas_neueregular',sans-serif;
box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #393333;
background-color: #950707;
}    

nav.main ul
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: right;
font-size: 1.45em;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

nav.main ul li
{
border-bottom: 1px solid  #af1b1b;
}

nav.main ul li:first-child
{
border-top: 1px solid  #af1b1b;
}

nav.main ul li a
{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
padding: 0.35em;
}

nav.main ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #ffffff;
}

div.mobilmenu
{
background-color: #950707;
}

div.mobilmenu a
{
text-decoration: none;
color: inherit;
}

div.mobilmenu a i
{
font-size: 1.75em;
padding: 0.32em;
}

div.mobilmenu a i:hover
{
background-color: #ffffff;
transition: 325ms ease;
}

#wrapper
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
transform: translate(0px, 0px);
transition: 0.15s ease;
}

#wrapper.active
{
transform: translate(15.750em, 0px);
}
```

Here's the jQuery script I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('a.nav-link').click(function () {
   $('nav#toggle').toggleClass('active');
   $('#wrapper').toggleClass('active');
 });
});
```

Comment: can you do us a favor and provide us with a jsFiddle or at least tell us what the problem is and what you expect it to do?

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/qsHRh/
What I'm trying to do is when you click on where it says "menu"  I want to make so that the ul list under the <nav> tag pops out from left to right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/qsHRh/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.nav-link').click(function () {
        $('nav#toggle').toggleClass('active');
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('active');
        });
    $('.nav-link').click(function(){
        $('#toggle').animate({left:'0px'},200);
        });
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if (!$('#toggle, .nav-link').is(e.target)   && $('#toggle').has(e.target).length === 0){
            $('#toggle').animate({left:'-15.750em'},200);
            }
        });
});
```

UPDATE:

you need to wrap your whole page into a div, let's call it #whole, and then give it the style, `position:relative; left:0; top:0;` and then shift the whole page as needed. check the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/qsHRh/3/

I think this is what you need. if not, let me know.

Comment: Pretty much yeah, but I also want to everything else over when the menu pops out.

Comment: what do you mean I want everything else over?

Comment: I mean everything between #wrapper. So the header, the bar where the menu button is in, the side bar, main content area, and footer.